# How to remove an asset from album without deleting the asset/photo from the photos app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, alassetslibrary, photosframework

I want to programmatically remove assets from an album which is a duplicate (the photos are not). I can delete the album using Photos framework

I want to know how to remove the asset from the album without deleting it completely from photos app. There are multiple places where I want to use this, eg to move asset from one album to another, etc

The albums are editable as I have created them.

Is there a way to do this in devices with iOS 6 or iOS 7?

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 8 and later you can use following code to remove a photo from an album without deleting the photo completely from photos app.

```
[[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
    PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest *request = [PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest
        changeRequestForAssetCollection:self.myAlbum
                                 assets:self.albumAssetsFetchResult];
    [request removeAssets:@[asset]];

} completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Finished removing asset from the album. %@", (success ? @"Success" : error));
}];
```

The code is provided at following link:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest_Class/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Swift 4 version of Tgiri's answer if it's helpful for anyone:

```
// you want to pass in your asset collection and asset
let album: PHAssetCollection 
let asset: PHAsset

PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
            guard let albumChangeRequest = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(for: album) else { return }
            let fastEnumeration = NSArray(array: [asset])
            albumChangeRequest.removeAssets(fastEnumeration)
        }, completionHandler: { success, error in
        if success {
            print("removed")
        } else {
            print("not removed")
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `imageData` of that image to nil, in that way you can delete an image.

```
ALAssetsLibrary *lib = [ALAssetsLibrary new];
[lib enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAlbum usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
{
     if(group == nil)
     {
          return ;
     }

     if([[group valueForProperty:ALAssetsGroupPropertyName] isEqualToString:@"YourAlbumNam"])
    {
        [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
        {
             if(asset.isEditable)
             {
                 if([[asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyAssetURL] isEqual:yourAssetURL] )
                 {
                       [asset setImageData:nil metadata:nil completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error)
                       {
                             // Check for error
                       }];
                 }
              }
        }];
    }                
failureBlock:^(NSError *error)
{

}];
```

Comment: I do not want to delete the asset. I only want to remove it from the album. It should exist in the camera roll

Comment: @ShravyaBoggarapu: It should exist in the camera roll, I'm only removing it from the album. Did you tried that code ?

Comment: its not working. and the thing is retrieved asset is not editable that's why it is not going further.